# Problems connecting to the API Xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm making an API on laravel, I run the server using the openserver console, the domain has http://127.0.0.1:8000.
I got a ClearText error, but I managed to fix it by adding it to the manifest config:`android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`, but now I get an error:

> failed to connect to / 127.0.0.1:8000

Here is my method:

```
private async void OnRegisterButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string name = NameEntry.Text;
    string email = EmailEntry.Text;
    string password = PasswordEntry.Text;
    string passwordConfirmation = PasswordConfirmationEntry.Text;

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(email) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(passwordConfirmation))
    {
        await DisplayAlert("Ошибка", "Заполните все поля", "OK");
        return;
    }

    var registrationData = new
    {
        name = name,
        email = email,
        password = password,
        password_confirmation = passwordConfirmation
    };

    try
    {
        string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(registrationData);

        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            HttpContent content = new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/register", content);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Успех", "Регистрация прошла успешно", "OK");
            }
            else
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Ошибка", "Произошла ошибка при регистрации", "OK");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        await DisplayAlert("Ошибка", "Произошла ошибка: " + ex.Message, "OK");
    }
}
```

Comment: do not use `127.0.0.1`, use the actual IP or FQDN of your server.  `localhost/127.0.0.1` will just cause your device to attempt to connect to itself